# Mac equivalent .bat file to perform terminal functions

Tags: macos, batch-file, terminal

Currently, I do the following commands in my terminal each time I want to work on a project:

```
cd desktop
cd folder
source bin/activate
cd src
python manage.py runserver
```

Is there a way to create a script that will run this on a Mac?

Ideally, I would like to be able to do the following:

```
x = 'What folder would you like to open?'
cd desktop
cd x
source bin/activate
cd src
python manage.py runserver
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "What folder would you like to open? "
read folder
cd ~/Desktop/$folder
source bin/activate
cd src
python manage.py runserver
```

Save those lines to something like `open_project.sh` and make it executable using

```
chmod +x open_project.sh
```

Then run it like

```
./open_project.sh
```

If you create a `bin` directory in your home directory, you can add put the script in there, add the `bin` directory to your path, and then you will be able to run the script from any directory using

```
open_project.sh
```